# Как добавить тэг к посту в форуме?

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Мне нужно по слэш команде создавать несколько постов в канале-форуме. Эти посты обязательно должны содержать метку (тэг) для того, чтобы было понятно к какой теме относится пост.

У меня возникла с этим проблема: я не понимаю как мне привязать тэг к посту. Вот мой код:

```py
CHANNEL = BOT.get_channel(id)

await CHANNEL.create_thread(applied_tags="Логотип", name="ветка", content="текст")
```

Он крашится с ошибкой:

```
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Я понимаю, что в `applied_tags` нужно передать `Snowflake`, а не строку. Но я не понимаю, как через этот класс (`Snowflake`) мне получить тэг, который мне нужно использовать.

Пробовал получить ID тега, но не получилось, у дискорда просто нет такой функции. Пробовал искать ответ в гугле, но видимо я еще не набрался скилла искать ответ к проблеме, поэтому решил обратиться за помощью сюда.

Как привязать тэг к посту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка возникла из-за того, что аргумент **applied_tags** принимает список тегов формата **discord.ForumTag**, а не их названия.

Для примера, создадим тег и прикрепим его к посту:

```
    CHANNEL = client.get_channel("channel_id") #Получаем канал-форум
    TAG = await CHANNEL.create_tag(name="Tag name") #Создаём тег
    await CHANNEL.create_thread(applied_tags=[TAG], name="Ветка", content="Текст") #Создаём пост, крепим к нему наш новый тег
```

Для получения уже существующего тега используем функцию **get_tag**, например:

```
    CHANNEL = client.get_channel("channel_id") #Получаем канал-форум
    TAG = await CHANNEL.get_tag("id") #Получаем тег по его ID
    await CHANNEL.create_thread(applied_tags=[TAG], name="Ветка", content="Текст") #Создаём пост, крепим к нему наш найденный тег
```

Comment: Заметил только после публикации, что вы используете библиотеку disnake, а не discord.py. Но разницы у них быть не должно, попробуйте данный вариант.

Comment: @q r t s , спасибо, мне это очень помогло. Оказывается, что я не внимательно смотрел документацию. В классе `ForumChannel` были функции благодаря которым я мог получить тэг, а я их где-то в другом месте искал..

Comment: @SuperFeda рад был помочь. С библиотекой disnake не работал, но знаю что ни довольно похожи с ds.py.